# Raise cupboard floor (under stairs)

Tags: floor, subfloor

We have a 1930s terraced house in London (UK) with a small cupboard under the stairs, its floor space is about 80cm x 190cm. The floor of this area is around 80cm lower than that of the hall that runs alongside it. I'd like to raise the cupboard floor level to that of the hall and am wondering what the best approach might be?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks,

Toby

Comment: Do you have pictures?

Comment: I don't and it's tricky, it's currently enclosed (there's a door into it) and awkward to get a decent picture of. Is there any more info I can provide that would help?

Comment: I found a [picture](http://dorkdaddydotcom.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/cupboard.jpg)! (Sorry, couldn't help it.)